# How do I make a font-size be "75% of what it otherwise would've been"

Tags: html, css

Basically, what I want is for all `font-size`s on mobile to be reduced to 75% of that they otherwise would. For example, if a `p` is `10px` then on mobile it will be `7.5px`.

So how do I do

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    body { font-size: 0.75whateveritwouldbeotherwise; }
}
```

Comment: I use just "font-size: 75%".

Comment: @James That clearly doesn't work

Comment: Try this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fzafmtu1/

Comment: A bit tedious, but short and simple for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use em units.

https://jsfiddle.net/wha9dh0j/

```
<div>test</div> //2em = twice the size of inherited size
<div>test</div> //body font, 30px
<div>test</div> //0.5em = half the size of inherited size

body{
  font-size:30px;
}

div:first-child{
  font-size:2em;
}

div:last-child{
  font-size:0.5em;
}
```

Comment: That's what I posted... :)